# Can this wok be saved?

Tags: seasoning, wok, maintenance

I'm new to seasoning woks, I started by cleaning it with water and then heating it on a high heat and then seasoning with oil.

It now looks like this? Is it savable, does it need reasoned?[image: wok picture here]

Comment: Welcome to the Cooking Stack Exchange, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site. We have a lot of questions on here about seasoning various types of cookware. Use the search bar to find some and have a browse through. I'll vote to close this as a duplicate, don't feel attacked, it's just how Stacks work, in that we try(!) to only have one of each type of question.

Comment: Was that a plain steel wok to start with, or did it already have some sort of non-stick coating?

Comment: Howdy!  There are many questions around seasoning woks.  Check the results of this search: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=seasoning+wok  Look at all the advice there, and then come back with specific detailed questions you feel are unanswered.    FWIW, it looks to me like you didn't apply the oil well when doing the seasoning.

Comment: I'm with brhans - that was a non-stick wok, now with the non-stick partly burned & scraped off. If you want to season it, first you're going to have to get rid of the rest of the non-stick, & start afresh, from raw steel. [Which actually makes it not a duplicate of the 2 linked, though I'm sure we do have a dupe of 'ruined my non-stick']

Comment: That doesn't look like a non-stick wok to me; looks more like carbon steel with the patchy seasoning characteristic of trying to use more Western-style pan seasoning techniques on a wok

Comment: @Tetsujin that is definitely not a non-stick wok.

Comment: @Blargant This looks to me like the grey coating coming off in chunks - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMme0.png

Comment: I'm seeing the opposite; the dark area is a layer of seasoning that's got a scratch or place where it didn't form fully; honestly, it reminds me of my own wok in the past

Comment: Thanks everyone for their comments! It's not non-stick, this is the exact Wok if that helps! Is it likely not savable then? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pre-Seasoned-Carbon-Steel-Wok-Pan/dp/B084DQYNNM/ref=asc_df_B084DQYNNM/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=501097834937&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17811995790130283976&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006886&hvtargid=pla-901648731080&psc=1